# cant install @angular/fire because of incompatibility issues

Tags: angular, firebase, npm, angularfire, ionic7

so i ran npm outdated and tried to install some outdated things there without knowing what it really does, thinking that i should update them.
and this is what i really need. i need to install angular fire and this shows

```
⠏ Installing packages (npm)...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: @ionic/angular-server@7.7.4
npm ERR! Found: @angular/animations@17.2.1
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   @angular/animations@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @angular/animations@"17.2.1" from @angular/platform-browser@17.2.1  
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-browser
npm ERR!     @angular/platform-browser@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-browser@"^17.0.0" from @angular/fire@17.0.1
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/fire
npm ERR!       @angular/fire@"^17.0.1" from the root project
npm ERR!     3 more (@angular/forms, @angular/platform-browser-dynamic, @angular/router)    
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer @angular/platform-server@">=14.0.0" from @ionic/angular-server@7.7.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@ionic/angular-server
npm ERR!   @ionic/angular-server@"^7.7.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/animations@17.2.4
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/animations
npm ERR!   peer @angular/animations@"17.2.4" from @angular/platform-server@17.2.4
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/platform-server
npm ERR!     peer @angular/platform-server@">=14.0.0" from @ionic/angular-server@7.7.4      
npm ERR!     node_modules/@ionic/angular-server
npm ERR!       @ionic/angular-server@"^7.7.4" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
```

the angular animations is till not on the wanted version of my project cause when i tried updating it, theres also an compatibility issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just run with force flag.

```
npm install @angular/fire --force
```